# Fedora 13 - No module named yum

Tags: fedora-13, yum

This is driving me bananas!
After a recent update in Fedora 13 64bit, my yum is gone:

```
$> yum update
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.
```

I tried looking for an RPM yum package - to install yum. I went to the Fedora site:
http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Tools/yum

Call me blind but I cannot find it anywhere on that page!

Most of the solutions suggest repairing yum... with yum! But I don't have yum? Yum yum yum? :<

Any help?

Here are some outputs for rpm commands:

```
$> rpm -ql python | grep "site-packages$"
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
$> rpm -ql yum | grep "site-packages/yum$"
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if your version of `python` doesn't match the version of `yum` properly. Run `rpm -ql python | grep "site-packages$"` and `rpm -ql yum | grep "site-packages/yum$"` and compare the output to make sure that the two are in sync.

Comment: Hi thanks, I've updated my question with the output. Looks the same

Comment: @drozzy: Does `rpm -V yum` output anything?

Comment: No, rpm -V yum does and shows nothing.

Comment: Well, it seems I overwrote my python binary with a custom complied "python altinstall". My original python was /usr/lib64/python2.6. Any way I can get back my original executable in /usr/bin/python?

Comment: `cd /usr/bin && rm python && ln -s python2.6 python`

Comment: Hm.. nope. I think the problem is that python2.6 is the same executable as python. I tried copying /usr/bin/python executable from another machine to this one - but when I run it - it shows the old version! It's as if it's pointing to something.... So on machine2 I have "python r264:75706", but on my machine it's "r266:84292".

Comment: That's really strange and shouldn't be a problem, since both have the same `site-packages` path. At this point I can only recommend that you download the `python.x86_64` package from a Fedora mirror and force install it via `rpm`.

Comment: That is an excellent idea! When I try to install rpm with " rpm -Uvh python-libs-2.6.4-25.fc13.x86_64.rpm " it says "python = 2.6.4-27.fc13 is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.6.4-27.fc13.x86_64", but the funny thing is when I try to install libs it says "python = 2.6.4-25.fc13 is needed by python-libs-2.6.4-25.fc13.x86_64". So it's like a loop!

Comment: You have to install both with the same command.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Kind-of. I did "sudo rpm -Uvh --force python-2.6.4-25.fc13.x86_64.rpm python-libs-2.6.4-25.fc13.x86_64.rpm 
" ... unfortunately the python still refers to the same version. Could it be that I needed to uninstall the old verion?

Comment: Did you perhaps install under `/usr/local` and then add `/usr/local/bin` to `$PATH`?

Comment: I don't think so. I mean I actually "cd /usr/local/bin" and run "python" and it shows "2.6.6", whereas the rpm I installed was clearly for python 2.6.4. I "cd /usr/bin" and run "python" and "python2.6" and STILL get 2.6.6... WOW this is so ridiculous - I think I am cursed. I think I'll have to reinstall Fedora.

Comment: The current directory isn't in `$PATH` in Linux, so you ran the same command both times. Try `./python` instead.

Comment: Wow, ok. I've actually manually deleted all of the "/usr/bin/python2.6, /user/bin/python2, /usr/local/bin/python2.6", after which I made sure that only "2.6.6" rpm was listed in "rpm -qa". After this running python results in "Command not found".

I then FORCE installed the 2.6.4 rpms of python. STILL when i run "python" I get 2.6.6! Something is intercepting the call to python or wiring it up or... i don't know. Maybe rpm installs 2.6.6.

Comment: Try `which python`. That will tell you which executable it tries to run.